# Use oEmbed for static html

Tags: oembed

I am trying to add a jQuery plugin (https://github.com/rmanivannan/speedometer-jquery-plugin) to a Wordpress page (not post), however the plugin is not behaving as expected. I think this may have something to do with the way the script references, css references and Javascript are mangled when the page is generated with my Wordpress theme.

Is it possible for to:
- Upload static HTML page containing the control to a subdomain
- Include the static HTML page in the Wordpress page using oEmbed

i.e. the subdomain will be an oEmbed provider to the primary domain?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. If you add the plugin assets correctly, you won't need this convoluted oEmbed solution. Search here for `enqueue` to learn how to correctly add scripts and styles to a WordPress page.

Comment: #Milo, I only want to add plugin to 1 page, not the entire site?

Answer (score 0):

`oEmbed` means in reality an `iframe` being added to the page. As such you do not need any `oembed` and you can just "include" your html page as an `iframe` while editing the page (assumin you are an admin).

Note: as @Milo said in the comments, you most likely ask for the wrong solution, the right one is probably to integrate whatever you have as a page template.